# Removing div based on selection in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

I have this navigation

```
<div class="col-3" id="record_nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="course-record selected" data-target="#upcoming"><span class="dot yellow"></span>Upcoming Week</li>
    <li class="course-record" data-target="#future"><span class="dot blue"></span>Further Weeks</li>
    <li class="course-record" data-target="#history"><span class="dot red"></span>History</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Inside my li tags I have a data-target selects an div that has those specific ids. The first one is display:block while the rest are display: none;

```
#future{
  display: none;
}

#history{
  display: none;
}

#upcoming{
  display: block;
}

.selected{
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);

}
```

In my jquery I have the li elements add and remove the selected class based on which one is selected. This works fine. But when I try to show and hide the data target, what ends up being removed is the li element selected itself. Im not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
  $('#record_nav ul li').on('click', function(e){
      $('#record_nav ul li.selected').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      var $this=$(e.target);
      console.log(e.target);
      $(this).not($this.data('target')).hide();
      $(this).filter($this.data('target')).show(300);
  });
```

```js
$('#record_nav ul li').on('click', function(e) {
  $('#record_nav ul li.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  var $this = $(e.target);
  console.log(e.target);
  $(this).not($this.data('target')).hide();
  $(this).filter($this.data('target')).show(300);
});
```

```css
#future {
  display: none;
}

#history {
  display: none;
}

#upcoming {
  display: block;
}

.selected {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-3" id="record_nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="course-record selected" data-target="#upcoming"><span class="dot yellow"></span>Upcoming Week</li>
    <li class="course-record" data-target="#future"><span class="dot blue"></span>Further Weeks</li>
    <li class="course-record" data-target="#history"><span class="dot red"></span>History</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The divs that I am trying to hide and show are like this

```
<div id="upcoming">some content</div>
<div id="future">some content</div>
<div id="history">some content</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to remove? Just the inner `span`?

Comment: What are those css selectors meant to affect the visibility of? There are no elements with those IDs.

Comment: No Its these separate divs with the ids #upcoming, #future, and #history that contain content.

Comment: What do you expect the output to be like?

Comment: Sorry I did not think I would need to include that code will update!

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal the output I am expecting is when you click that specific list item in the navigation. The id's that are targeted will either show or be hidden

Comment: @dutchkillsg ok I have added the answer accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can associate a class called `content` in those `div` which you want to hide and show so that we can use this class selector to hide those `div`. Now, you can use `.data()` to get the `data-target` value and show it:

```js
$('#record_nav ul li').on('click', function(e){
      $('#record_nav ul li.selected').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      $('.content').hide();
      var id = $(this).data('target');
      $(id).show();
  });
```

```css
#future{
  display: none;
}

#history{
  display: none;
}

#upcoming{
  display: block;
}

.selected{
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-3" id="record_nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="course-record selected" data-target="#upcoming"><span class="dot yellow"></span>Upcoming Week</li>
    <li class="course-record" data-target="#future"><span class="dot blue"></span>Further Weeks</li>
    <li class="course-record" data-target="#history"><span class="dot red"></span>History</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="upcoming" class='content'>some content upcoming</div>
<div id="future" class='content'>some content future</div>
<div id="history" class='content'>some content history</div>
```

Comment: you can accomplish the hide all without the additional content class `$($("li.course-record").map(function() {return $(this).data("target")}).get().join()).hide();`

Comment: @Steve why to have a additional custom loop when we can simply make our code simple by adding a class. Your suggestion is also useful.

Comment: I was just mentioning it incase someone stumbles across your answer and need a slightly different method.